# Can we use Chinese remainder theorem to "shrink" a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, chinese-remainder-theorem

Suppose that we have a field $p^k$, and we want to express values in this field modulo smaller fields $(q_1)^k$, $(q_2)^k$,...  I believe that there is a way to do this using the Chinese remainder theorem, if we can find a polynomial that is irreducible modulo $p^k$, and completely reducible modulo the smaller fields.

My question is, can we do this, and how small can we make the largest prime $q^k$, if we know what $p$ and $k$ are?

Comment: $\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$ is a ring, but it's different from the field with $p^k$ elements

Comment: What do you mean by "a field $p^k$"? What exactly is $p$ here? What is $k$?

Comment: Subfields are not ideals, so you won't be able to apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  Hmmm...  I'll have to study some more, I guess.  I'm really looking for some way to "compress" a field, but perhaps this isn't possible. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I am not sure what you mean by "shrinking" a field, it seems like you mean some sort of (quotient?) map from a field to a "smaller" field.

In fact, this isn't really possible for any sensible notion of "being smaller". Recall that in set theory, we can define a notion of cardinality in the following way: For $M, N$ sets, $|M| \leqslant |N|$ means that there exists an injective map $M \rightarrow N$. Then, $|M| < |N|$ means that there does not exist an injective map $N \rightarrow M$.

Now, let $F, G$ be fields and $\varphi : F \rightarrow G$ be a field homomorphism. $\varphi$ is necessarily injective! To see this, consider $\ker \varphi$. If there is a non-zero element $a \in \ker \varphi$, then $1 = \varphi(1) = \varphi(aa^{-1}) = \varphi(a)\varphi(a^{-1}) = 0$. Thus, the kernel needs to be trivial, and $\varphi$ is injective. (Alternatively, you can see this by considering that $\ker \varphi$ needs to be an ideal of $F$ as a ring, and fields only have $F, (0)$ as ideals).

Putting this result together with our notion of "being smaller", this means that if there exists a mapping $F \rightarrow G$, we always have $|F| \leqslant |G|$.